# How do I add back the transparent background around my dialog activity with a custom theme

Tags: android, xml, dialog, android-styles, android-dialog

I have an activity and I've set it's theme in the manifest to a custom dialog theme.
But now the transparency around the dialog box is gone. Everything is black.

Here's what it looks like with my custom theme:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

But with a custom background and text color, like in the first picture.

Here's the part of the manifest with the activity's theme set to my custom theme, as in the first picture:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.LockScreenActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/aplicacao_bloqueada_title"
        android:theme="@style/dialog_theme"/>
```

Here's the part of the manifest with the activity's theme set to android's dialog theme, as in the second picture:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.LockScreenActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/aplicacao_bloqueada_title"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog"/>
```

Here's my xml with my custom theme:

```
<style name="dialog_theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog">

        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/dark_gray</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">50</item>

</style>
```

Here's my activity class:

```
public class LockScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Notification activity that is called after too many failed login attempts

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lock_screen);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                finishAndRemoveTask();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

Layout for my activity:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".activity.LockScreenActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="214dp"
        android:layout_height="136dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="@string/aplicacao_bloqueada_text"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What's the best way to do this?

Edit: As [nima](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16780065/nima) sugested, I tried adding the following line to the onCreat method of my dialog themed class:

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

But it turned everything transparent, including the pop up window.
See picture:

[image]

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @nima pointed out you can use `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));` to make the background transparent.

This will introduce a couple of issues:

- Transparency of everything

  Fix this by setting a white background to the `ConstraintLayout` root layout.
- Transparent activity title

  Fix this by removing the title from the manifest and set it to an empty one in activity with `setTitle("")`; and add another `TextView` to represent the title in the layout:

Remove the title (android:label) from the activity in the manifest:
Also you should `android:exported="true"` as it seems that this activity should be exported to other apps:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.LockScreenActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog"/>
```

Set the title & background:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lock_screen);
   
    // ...........

    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    setTitle("");

}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    tools:context=".LockScreenActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Application Blocked"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="214dp"
        android:layout_height="136dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="@string/aplicacao_bloqueada_text"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**UPDATE:**

> When I use my custom theme, as opposed to Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog, I still get the black screen

This is because the `android:backgroundDimAmount` is set to 50 in your custom theme; the valid range for this attribute is 0 through 1; any value greater than that will be considered 1...

0 means there is no dimming (completely transparent, and 1 meaning 100% opaque/black.

So to fix this issue, I guess you mean by 50 as the half way, so you'd set it to 0.5 instead:

```
<style name="dialog_theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/dark_gray</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.5</item>
</style>
```

Comment: When I use my custom theme, as opposed to Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog, I still get the black screen. :/

Comment: @LailaCampos .. This is due to the `android:backgroundDimAmount`, please check the updated answer at the `UPDATE` section.

Comment: I partially followed your instructions and here's how I achieved the result I wanted: I put `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));` and `setTitle("");` inside the onCreate method. I set the theme in the manifest to the default dialog theme `@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog`. I've created another TextView for the title like you said. I've changed the background color for my constraint layout and I set the textColor propriety of both TextViews to white.

Comment: Should I mark your question as the answer? Or should I created another answer and explain everything I did differently? Genuine question here.
Also, thank you very much.

Comment: @LailaCampos I guess you now need to set the theme to yours at the manifest: `android:theme="@style/dialog_theme"`; I assumed that already as you need to use it instead of the default... I couldn't see difference in the procedure you followed other than the answer.. If there is essential part that you did solve your problem not mentioned in the answer, you can write another answer, and just upvote my ansewer, if there is no big deal you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Edit Your Code Like Bellow:
1-In `style`

```
    <style name="dialog_theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog">

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>

</style>
```

2-In `Manifest`

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.LockScreenActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/dialog_theme"
        android:label=""
        />
```

3-`activity_lock_screen`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="170dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="214dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:text="Application Blocked !"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="214dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_weight=".4"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:text="@string/aplicacao_bloqueada_text"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried it but now the screen is all black. Pop up window is gone. And about the e_alertdialogok_layout, I can't find it. It says it cannot resolve that symbol.

Comment: oh sorry.use activity_lock_screen instead e_alertdialogok_layout

Comment: The screen is still black. Even if I set the theme to the default dialog one in the manifest. :/

Comment: What is the main activity theme?

Comment: This may be a problem with the Android emulator
Try it with a real phone too

Comment: I was trying it with my custom theme. The screen is all black with it. When I tried with the theme Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog, it turned eveything transparent, which is not what I want. I'll update the question with a photo.

Comment: If possible, write the name of the theme you used for the main activity here

Comment: I didn't set up a theme for the main activity in the manifest, so I assume it's the default theme.

Comment: if dont set up then android use application tag theme.what is application theme?

Comment: Using alertDialog is better than the method you use. I recommend using alertDialog

Answer (score -1):

Your `backgroundDimAmount` is too high try some smaller number like `0.5`

So your `dialog_theme` would look something like this.

```
<style name="dialog_theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog">

        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/dark_gray</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.5</item>

    </style>
```

Comment: Thank you but I tried it and nothing changed. I still have the same black background around my dialog.